# Image gets cutt off when positioning outside of a modal window

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, colorbox

I have this html file:

```
<div style="
width:400px;
height:300px;
background-color:#009966;">
</div>
```

I'm opening it as a modal window with colorbox, that has this CSS:

```
#cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper, #colorbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#cboxWrapper {
    max-width: none;
}
#cboxOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%}
#cboxBottomLeft, #cboxMiddleLeft {
    clear: left;
}
#cboxContent {
    position: relative;
}
#cboxLoadedContent {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#cboxTitle {
    margin: 0;
}
#cboxLoadingGraphic, #cboxLoadingOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%}
#cboxClose, #cboxNext, #cboxPrevious, #cboxSlideshow {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cboxPhoto {
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    max-width: none;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
.cboxIframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
}
#cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent, #colorbox {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cboxOverlay {
    background: #000;
}
#colorbox {
    outline: 0;
}
#cboxContent {
    margin-top: 32px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.cboxIframe {
    background: #fff;
}
#cboxError {
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#cboxLoadedContent {
    padding: 1px;
}
#cboxLoadingGraphic {
    background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
#cboxLoadingOverlay {
    background: #000;
}
#cboxTitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    left: 0;
    color: #000;
}
#cboxCurrent {
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    right: 205px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#cboxClose {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left:390px;
    background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat;
}
#cboxClose:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxPrevious:active, #cboxSlideshow:active {
    outline: 0;
}
#cboxPrevious {
    background-position: 0 0;
    right: 44px;
}
#cboxPrevious:hover {
    background-position: 0 -25px;
}
#cboxNext {
    background-position: -25px 0;
    right: 22px;
}
#cboxNext:hover {
    background-position: -25px -25px;
}
#cboxClose {
    background-position: -50px 0;
    right: 0;
}
#cboxClose:hover {
    background-position: -50px -25px;
}
.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxPrevious, .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxPrevious {
    right: 66px;
}
.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow {
    background-position: -75px -25px;
    right: 44px;
}
.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow:hover {
    background-position: -100px -25px;
}
.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow {
    background-position: -100px 0;
    right: 44px;
}
.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow:hover {
    background-position: -75px -25px;
}
```

I've tried playing with the position of the "X" button, I want it to be outside of the DIV, say 50px to the top and 50px to the right, by modifying `#cboxClose`, but that image gets cutted off, as you can see in the photo.

[image]

what's causing this?

Comment: Is the code live somewhere? Or can you put it up (including js) on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: not really, it's too many sources including images, can't see how I can efficiently put it on a fiddle.

Comment: @nicolekanderson you can see [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/) a different live example - AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container `#cboxWrapper` has `overflow: hidden;` set (near the top of your included CSS); if you add `overflow: visible;` to that selector, your moved X button should be visible.

I wouldn't recommend changing the original `overflow: hidden;` declaration, since it involves other selectors, but just adding the the following:

```
#cboxWrapper {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! actually I had to change both `#cboxWrapper, #colorbox` for it to work, changing only one of them wouldn't work. can it hurt the performance of the modal window in any way? also, is it possible to define the position of that x button with a `right` attribute rather than a left? I've tried a negative right value, but it only got to the edge of the modal window. works with left though.